# how to get value of single value from the fetched row in nodejs and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
about_model.getDob(req.params.id,function(err,rows) {
    locals.dob = rows[0].user_dob;
    // res.send(rows[0].user_dob);
    res.render('about',locals);
});
```

In above code , when i am using `res.send(rows[0].user_dob)` then it prints correct result but when i want to save the value of `rows[0].user_dob` in `locals.dob` then it is giving me error that

> cannot read property of 'undefined'

please solve this issue.

Comment: Where is locals coming from? Is it defined.

Comment: yes it is defined above the code... var locals = {};

Comment: What happen if you put conosle.log(locals.dob) before to call res.render?

Comment: actually it is printing the correct result ... but same error arises at console and it stop the server

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere in the rendering. Check if your template exists and if there is correct usage of variables inside.